# is it possible to do a basic authentication to a NON-salesforce domain system using Page Reference object?

Tags: apex

I have a problem setting Authorization headers on Page Reference object in Salesforce. The code performs a GET HTTP request to the URL specified . But it's not reading the headers & not automatically login into the external site. Do you know what can be the problem?

My code looks like this:

```
Blob header = Blob.valueOf(uname+ ':' + psswd);
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(header);
PageReference page = new PageReference( URL);
page.getHeaders().put('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
 pgref.setRedirect(true);
```

Comment: are you trying to make an API call or navigating to a page? Because that's not how you perform a REST GET Request.

Comment: I am trying to redirect to an external page where basic authentication is enabled. That's the reason why I am using PageReference object instead of HttpRequest object. Is there any way I can accomplish this with PageReference object? The problem with PageReference is it doesn't carry the header information even if I am explicitly setting it in the code as above.

Comment: @CHINUJOY Did you find the answer? If yes, how did you redirect from visualforce page with authorization header?

Comment: @SebastianKessel, any Idea on how to redirect with authorization header from visualforce page?